# how to pass an unknown amount of values in an IN condition in a SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a function that has an in condition and the values in it are supposed to be passed as a parameter

```
WHERE ITEM_CODE IN (@dynamicAmountOfInputs)
```

but i'm not sure if this is possible or how do I pass the values during the method enclosed by single quotes and separated by commas.

DB is MS SQL, Version is SQL Server 2008

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: If SQL server 2008 onwards, consider [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Comment: Or if you really hate the world you could pass an XML as a parameter :-)

Comment: there's a good amount of decent knowledge here http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: It's better if you write the language you'll call your function from, SQL, C#, VB.NET ... so the one who will help you will be able to write even the "client" code.

Comment: @Constanta Good link, that's the resource I was looking to post but you got there first. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, assuming the list is comma separated with no spaces after the commas (and no comma in the codes):

```
WHERE ','+@dynamicAmountOfInputs+',' like '%,'+ITEM_CODE+',%';
```

Unfortunately, this prevents the use of an index on `ITEM_CODE`.